# Direct Media and Direct RTP Setup in Asteisk

Tags: asterisk

I want to set direct peer to peer media setup in asterisk I used 
`directrtpsetup=yes`

Also I want to achieve it without re-Invite.So I use this parameter.In sip.conf its written that it works without re-Invite,But its not working for me.Any one please help me how to solve it.

I want to bypass asterisk for media.

Comment: Please post sip.conf [general], the sip configs for the two endpoints and the section of the dial plan where you dial the extension.

Answer (score 3):

Please note, directrtpsetup not work with nat nor if sdp offer DIFFERENT for both peers.

Also require both directmedia and directrtpsetup directives and asterisk version above 11.*

```
;directmedia=yes                ; Asterisk by default tries to redirect the
                                ; RTP media stream to go directly from
                                ; the caller to the callee.  Some devices do not
                                ; support this (especially if one of them is behind a NAT).
                                ; The default setting is YES. If you have all clients
                                ; behind a NAT, or for some other reason want Asterisk to
                                ; stay in the audio path, you may want to turn this off.

                                ; This setting also affect direct RTP
                                ; at call setup (a new feature in 1.4 - setting up the
                                ; call directly between the endpoints instead of sending
                                ; a re-INVITE).

                                ; Additionally this option does not disable all reINVITE operations.
                                ; It only controls Asterisk generating reINVITEs for the specific
                                ; purpose of setting up a direct media path. If a reINVITE is
                                ; needed to switch a media stream to inactive (when placed on
                                ; hold) or to T.38, it will still be done, regardless of this
                                ; setting. Note that direct T.38 is not supported.

;directmedia=nonat              ; An additional option is to allow media path redirection
                                ; (reinvite) but only when the peer where the media is being
                                ; sent is known to not be behind a NAT (as the RTP core can
                                ; determine it based on the apparent IP address the media
                                ; arrives from).

;directmedia=update             ; Yet a third option... use UPDATE for media path redirection,
                                ; instead of INVITE. This can be combined with 'nonat', as
                                ; 'directmedia=update,nonat'. It implies 'yes'.

;directmedia=outgoing           ; When sending directmedia reinvites, do not send an immediate
                                ; reinvite on an incoming call leg. This option is useful when
                                ; peered with another SIP user agent that is known to send
                                ; immediate direct media reinvites upon call establishment. Setting
                                ; the option in this situation helps to prevent potential glares.
                                ; Setting this option implies 'yes'.
```

.

```
;directrtpsetup=yes             ; Enable the new experimental direct RTP setup. This sets up
                                ; the call directly with media peer-2-peer without re-invites.
                                ; Will not work for video and cases where the callee sends
                                ; RTP payloads and fmtp headers in the 200 OK that does not match the
                                ; callers INVITE. This will also fail if directmedia is enabled when
                                ; the device is actually behind NAT.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, I have gotten directmedia to work behind NAT with SIP ALG enabled. That assumes you have a router with a working SIP ALG mode.  Many routers do not work properly with SIP ALG but it seems to be improving over time.