# Asterisk RTP data to Node.JS app

Tags: node.js, asterisk, voip, rtp, pjsip

I've successfully set up Asterisk on my server using the res_pjsip Hello World configuration from their wiki, and I want to be able to forward the RTP data to a Node.JS app, which can interpret RTP. I've heard about `directmedia` and `directrtpsetup` (see [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497913/direct-media-and-direct-rtp-setup-in-asteisk#35516620)) but I'm not sure if that's what I want. So my question is this:

Should I use `directmedia` / `directrtpsetup` to send voice data to my Node.JS app, or should I use some sort of Asterisk functionality to forward RTP packets? If the latter, how can Asterisk forward just the voice data?

I can clarify if needed, but hopefully this is more specific than my last questions. Thanks!

UPDATE: Having poked around Asterisk docs and messing with Wireshark, I think I have two options.

1. Figure out if there's a channel driver for Asterisk that just sends RTP, without any signaling, or
2. Capture the RTP stream with Wireshark or something and send the packets to the Node.JS app, and inject the return packets into the RTP stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk is PBX. It not suitable to "redirect rtp data"

No, there are no reason in having channel driver "without signalling". For what anyone can use it? How to determine call started if "no signaling"? It will be useless.

You can write such app in c/c++ or use other soft designed to be traffic capture: libpcap, tcpdump etc.

You also can use audio staff: libalsa, jack.

Best option however will be create or find full featured sip client and use it.

Comment: Yeah, Asterisk was only going to let me proxy the call to the app, and it seems that there's no good way to do this without implementing a basic SIP client or using a library in the Node.JS app. Thanks for answering.